# Why did sqldf in R give this syntax error?

Tags: sql, r, left-join, sqldf

I tried package sqldf in R. I tried a very easy join. However, I got this syntax error.

```
library(sqldf)

radius1 <- sqldf("select radius.*, all.height, all.bmi
                  from radius left join all
                  on radius.uID = all.study_id
                 ")
```

> `Error: near "all": syntax error`

What is wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is that `all` is a reserved word in SQL queries. Try naming the data frame something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neilfws has rightly pointed out;
`all` is a reserved keyword in SQL queries and so is the syntax error.

If you still want to use "all" table name; you can surround it using backticks as below :

```
library(sqldf)

radius1 <- sqldf("select radius.*, `all`.height, `all`.bmi
                  from radius left join `all`
                  on radius.uID = `all`.study_id
                 ")
```